# Change the comment font in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How do you change the default font of comments (whether inline or bubble) in Microsoft Word 2007?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to bring up the Styles window. Click **Manage Styles** (third button at the very bottom of the window).

Edit the font settings for the entries below (for easy browsing, sort them alphabetically).
For each, make sure that **New documents based on this template** is selected (near the bottom of the window).

- Comment Reference
- Comment Subject
- Comment Text
- Balloon Text (this will let you change the font of the comment label)

Comment: That's odd. I'm pressing CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S, and nothing happens.

Comment: If the shortcut doesn't work, you can, in the Home ribbon tab, click the pop-out button in the lower right corner of the Styles section (or in Word 2019 search for "styles" in the `Tell me what to do` search box)