# Increase the size of the comment column Microsoft Word

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

Is there any way to increase the size of the comment column in Microsoft Word 2013?

[image]

I use Microsoft Word 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. I am aware of [Change the comment font in Microsoft Word 2007](https://superuser.com/q/285104/116475).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I've found which affects this is view > full screen reading. In the settings (top right) allow editing. I've found both view 1 & 2 page options only show 1 page, but 2 page is slightly bigger. Thus: full screen reading w/ 2 page view gives you a wider page layout (more text per line) AND comment area (more text per line also). Since the page height is compressed, you have fewer words per page thus probably fewer comments (i.e. some comments will follow their parent text onto preceding/succeeding pages), with more space per comment due to the width, resulting in a significantly lower chance of comments being compressed.

However:

1. You lose the ribbon & thus its associated functionality (though in word 2010 & up you have tons of functionality in the right click, and full screen view does give you some stuff in the mini ribbon e.g. highlighter & comment. Also worth remembering you can access most things via keyboard shortcut, especially ctrl+alt+M for comment).
2. You can't have the navigation pane on the left hand side, which is a shame.
3. You can't do split screen view, which is probably less of an issue for regular use.